# Lexical difference between classical and modern standard arabic

Tags: arabic

I've seen that linguists do not consider *fuṣḥa* as one, but two varieties: classical and modern.

I know that the grammar is nearly identical, but how about the lexicon? false friends etc? Is there for example a study that gives a percentage of similarity?

Comment: Not an answer, but I found a blog post by Lameen Souag mentioning that some Quranic Arabic vocabulary could be obscure even to people who spoke something like Classical Arabic: [Seaweed from Hell? A Qur'ānic hapax legomenon in a modern Arabic dialect](http://lughat.blogspot.com/2015/08/seaweed-from-hell-quranic-hapax.html)